# How to annotate Express middlewares with JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, express, webstorm, jsdoc

I'm trying to document an Express middleware, but the build-in validation tool in WebStorm tells me that types are incorrectly assigned in the following JSDoc block:

```
/**
 * My middleware.
 *
 * @param {Object} req
 * @param {Object} res
 * @param {Function} next
 * @return {Object}
 */
exports.show = function(req, res, next) {
    ...
};
```

In Express sources, I didn't find any `@typedef`s to help me. Also, I want to avoid things like `@param {*}`.

What is the correct way to document Express middleware using JSDoc? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try removing the `@return` line? Express routes often don't return anything.

Comment: Webstorm should hint you on what's the error though, no?

Comment: How are you adding this middleware to your app?

Comment: add a description after the @return {Object}, that did fix the issue for me in the past, or you can use eslint jsdoc validation for telling what is going sour

Answer (score 21):

You can document your middleware with

```
const express = require("express");

/**
 * @param {express.Request} req
 * @param {express.Response} res
 * @param {express.NextFunction} next
 */
function (req, res, next) {}
```

when you have middleware that add attribute to req, you can also add them with

```
const express = require("express");

/**
 * @param {express.Request & {specialParam1 : string, specialParam2 : any}} req
 * @param {express.Response} res
 * @param {express.NextFunction} next
 */
function (req, res, next) {}
```

or event better, create a typedef for each source of new elem added on "req" and use "&" to create a type combining them all.

Comment: This has the major advantage of including all of the methods/properties defined on `express.Request`. The downside is that you can't easily document e.g. each request body property individually like you can with dotted notation shown in the other answers. I haven't figured out a way to achieve both.

Comment: `@param {import('express').Request} req` too works if not have express as dependency

Answer (score 17):

### Use DefinitelyTyped

1. Install express types `npm install --save-dev @types/express`
2. use **e.Response** as usually `@param {e.Response} res`

### More types

- in file `/node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts`
- for **Response** it is **e.Response** because:

`...
declare namespace e {
    ...
    export interface Response extends core.Response { }
    ...`

### WebStorm

install types via Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Javascript > Libraries > @types/express

Answer (score 9):

First, we agree that middleware are functions; no special type declaration will generally be warranted. Beyond that, middleware tend to be highly decoupled—*modular*—which means the `@module` tag is usually applicable (and this has nice consequences when you run jsdoc).

```
/**
 * Description of my middleware.
 * @module myMiddleware
 * @function
 * @param {Object} req - Express request object
 * @param {Object} res - Express response object
 * @param {Function} next - Express next middleware function
 * @return {undefined}
 */
```

The return tag is optional depending on your style guide, since middleware don't return a value. Finally, contrary to what Nick and mmm claim, the `next` parameter is a function.

> http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html
>
> Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request
>   object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware
>   function in the application’s request-response cycle. *The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named next.*

`next` isn't a fancy Express-internal concoction; Express passes each middleware function the request, the response, and the next middleware function in the stack, like this:

```
mw1 = function(req, res, next){}.bind(undefined, req, res, mw2)
mw2 = function(req, res, next){}.bind(undefined, req, res, mw3)
```

The value of `next` within the scope of `mw1` is `mw2`.

Answer (score 8):

You can not only JsDoc the parameter types and descriptions, and but also their expected members.

```
/**
 * 
 * @module myMiddleware
 * @function
 * @param req {Object} The request.
 * @param res {Object} The response.
 * @param req.params.foo {String} The foo param.
 * @param req.query.bar {String} The bar query.
 * @param req.body {Object} The JSON payload.
 * @param {Function} next
 * @return {undefined}
 */
function foo(req, res, next){
}
```

Comment: Is documenting the parameter members this way an official suggestion?

Comment: I just copied your answer as an answer to my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771798/how-do-i-jsdoc-parameters-to-web-request/57777864#57777864

Answer (score 8):

[2021-03-02 Update] Original answer is like 100% JSDOC + 0% typescript, but I found a 20% JSDOC + 80% typescript (pure definition) solution. In [typescript github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio#JsDoc), it mentioned this method. See the final paragraph in post.

I combine other answer and modify some code,
it could include all of the methods/properties defined on `express.Request` and event custom request body.
It could not only use in `request.body`, but also support in `req.query`.
That because `express.Request` support generics, so we could use this in JSDoc.

First, remember to install `@types/express` with `npm install --save-dev @types/express`.

Second, setup like following code.

```js
// @ts-check
/**
 * @typedef {object} showRequestBody
 * @property {string} name this is name in request body
 * @property {number} age this is age in request body
 * 
 * @typedef {object} showRequestQuery
 * @property {string} name this is name in query
 * @property {number} age this is age in query
 * 
 * @param {import('express').Request<{}, {}, showRequestBody, showRequestQuery>} req
 * @param {import('express').Response} res 
 * @param {import('express').NextFunction} next 
 */
exports.show = function(req, res, next) {
};
```

Note: I use it in vscode.
I leave answer here, and I hope this will help other people also have this question.

---

other methods/properties defined on `express.Request`, for example `req.headers`

[image]

---

`req.body` hint

[image]

---

`req.query` hint

[image]

### 20% JSDOC + 80% typescript

The following example doesn't need `tsconfig.json` or install extra `tsc`.
But, you couldn't use jsdoc to generate documentation.

#### With import + export definition

If you want to extend interface with importing some module, you need to use export in definition. Then import it in JSDOC.

[image]

[image]

#### Without import + export definition

If you don't want to import custom definition in JSDOC, you could just define the interface without import and export. Then, you could directly use it in JSDOC.

[image]

[image]

#### Extend the express module

There is another way to build custom interface, just use declare module to extend the interface. You could even define custom method.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`req`, `res` and `next` are all objects, and a middleware usually doesn't return, so the following may be used.

```
/**
 * My Middleware
 * @name MyMiddleWare
 * @function
 * @param {Object} req
 * @param {Object} res
 * @param {Object} next
 */
```

Comment: If a function doesn't explicitly return a value, it implicitly returns `undefined`. Depending on the style guide you follow, this may or may not be explicitly called out with a @return tag: `@return {undefined}`. Google's Closure Compiler style guide forbids it, for example. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags

Comment: `Object` means `any`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to change is the `@param {Function}` next to `@param {Object}`. Also, `@return` should describe what the function returns; e.g, `(Object, Array)` or a combination `({Object|Null})`

Comment: Middleware typically return `undefined` - many developers treat the return tag as optional or improper when the function does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to see how to do this in 2022. And I ended up doing the following based on the current highest voted answer:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

/**
 * Some Middleware
 * @param {Request} req
 * @param {Response} res
 * @param {NextFunction} next
 * @returns
 */
export function someMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  ...
}
```

I'm using VSCode, and it detects the req, res, and next objects. I hope this helps someone!