# How do I jsdoc parameters to web request?

Tags: node.js, firebase, jsdoc

I have functions like this (in Node.js/Firebase) and wonder how to add documentation i JSDoc format:

```
exports.getUserRes = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {...}
```

How do I document the GET/POST/etc parameters to the `request`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I combine other answer in [How to annotate Express middlewares with JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266857/how-to-annotate-express-middlewares-with-jsdoc/65108929) and modify some code,
it could include all of the methods/properties defined on `express.Request` and event custom request body.
It could not only use in `request.body`, but also support in `req.query`.
That because `express.Request` support generics, so we could use this in JSDOC.

First, remember to install `@types/express` with `npm install --save-dev @types/express`.

Second, setup like following code.

```js
// @ts-check
/**
 * @typedef {object} showRequestBody
 * @property {string} name this is name in request body
 * @property {number} age this is age in request body
 * 
 * @typedef {object} showRequestQuery
 * @property {string} name this is name in query
 * @property {number} age this is age in query
 * 
 * @param {import('express').Request<{}, {}, showRequestBody, showRequestQuery>} req
 * @param {import('express').Response} res 
 * @param {import('express').NextFunction} next 
 */
exports.show = function(req, res, next) {
};
```

Note: I use it in vscode.

---

other methods/properties defined on `express.Request`, for example `req.headers`

[image]

---

`req.body` hint

[image]

---

`req.query` hint

[image]

Comment: If iwant to add custom properties in the res object, how to annotate that using jsdoc... req.error() or req.success()

Answer (score 1):

I just found an old question with an answer that seems to suggest a good way. It is not the accepted answer there I mean, but the answer by @Steven Spunkin:

> javascript - How to annotate Express middlewares with JSDoc? - Stack
>   Overflow
>   [How to annotate Express middlewares with JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266857/how-to-annotate-express-middlewares-with-jsdoc)

I am copying his answer here for simplicity. Comments are welcome!

```
/**
 * 
 * @module myMiddleware
 * @function
 * @param req {Object} The request.
 * @param res {Object} The response.
 * @param req.params.foo {String} The foo param.
 * @param req.query.bar {String} The bar query.
 * @param req.body {Object} The JSON payload.
 * @param {Function} next
 * @return {undefined}
 */
function foo(req, res, next){ ... }
```