# Explicitly Set Types on express.js IRouterMatcher

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jsdoc

Referencing the answers on [How to annotate Express middlewares with JSDoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266857/how-to-annotate-express-middlewares-with-jsdoc), there are answers on how to add types to express methods with JSDoc. They all generally give a way to type your handlers with `@param` and optionally extend the `express.Request` and `express.Response` interfaces.

Express methods are defined using an `IRouterMatcher` type you can see defined [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L127). The type parameters of `IRouterMatcher` are used in the `handlers` that get passed to instances of it so that all your handlers use the same `ResBody`, `ReqBody` types, etc.

In cases where there is a single handler, of course, this is not a problem.

In cases where there are multiple handlers, you can see the types being enforced.

```js
api.get(
    "/person",
    (req: express.Request<{}, { name: string, age: number }>, res) => {
        res.send({ name: "joe", age: 5 });
    },
    (req, res) => {
        // ts(2345) error at 'color'
        res.send({ name: "joe", color: "red" });
    });
```

In a syntax using generic type parameters I like more

```js
api.get<{id: number}, { name: string, age: number }>(
    "/person",
    (req, res) => {
        res.send({ name: "joe", age: 5 });
    },
    (req, res) => {
        // ts(2345) error at 'color'
        res.send({ name: "joe", color: "red" });
    });
```

In JavaScript using JSDoc with ts-check, I can get the same error on *all* handlers if I annotate both `req` and `res` (`ResBody` is defined on both) on at least one of them.

```js
api.get("/person",
    /**
     * @param {express.Request<{}, { name: string, age: number }>} req
     * @param {express.Response<{ name: string, age: number }>} res
     */
    (req, res) => {
        res.send({ name: "joe", age: 5 });
    },
    (req, res) => {
        // ts(2345) error at 'color'
        res.send({ name: "joe", color: "red" });
    });
```

However, this is annoying duplication and if I take away type information from either `req` or `res` then the type checking goes away - so I have to have both. Ideally, it would be nice to supply generic types to `IRouterMatcher` (`get`, `post`, etc.,) and have them enforced top-down like the second TypeScript example above but instead using JSDoc, but [it seems passing generic types to methods is not possible in JSDoc (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691957).

This seems like a problem begging for a workaround. I'm hoping passing generic types *is* something you can do in JSDoc, but given [the GitHub issue on the TS repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27387) linked in [the post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65691957) has been open since 2018, I don't have high hopes. I'm thinking there has to be a workaround though, but nothing I've tried has worked so far.